# jquery mobile images dynamic loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I'm using phongap 1.5, jquery 1.7.1, jquery mobile 1.1.0

in a multipage template I have this html:

```
<ul data-role="listview" id="listviewPreferiti"></ul>
```

when a button is tapped this js is executed
(I prefere this approach to json and javascript expansion):

```
$("ul[id="listviewPreferiti"] li").remove();
$("#listviewPreferiti").append(res).listview("refresh");
```

or this code that works the same as before:
    $("#listviewPreferiti").html(res).listview("refresh");

res is a list of 'li' like this:

```
<li><a id="1" href="#">
    <img src="http://www.pippo.com/images/02.jpg" class="ui-li-thumb"/>
    <p>some text</p>
</a></li>
<li><a id="2" href="#">
    <img src="http://www.pippo.com/images/03.jpg" class="ui-li-thumb"/>
    <p>some other text</p>
</a></li>
```

the rendering usually work BUT: sometimes the images are not displayed until i tap the screen. I suppose that the reason is: the rendering process of jquery mobile finishes before the loading of the images (infact once the images are loaded, the problem does not occurr, reloading the same listview).

How can i force the rendering of the images?
(i tryed using jquery .live, but no luck)(I'm using an android 4 phone for tests)

EDIT
I've found this horrible patch to the problem
after the append i call: refreshListView(listviewPreferiti,8);
(i tryed $('img').trigger('refresh') dut doesn't work)

```
var refreshListView = function(listName, times){
    if (times >0){
        setTimeout(function() {
            $("ul[id="+ listName +"] li img").each(function(index) {
                this.style.borderBottom = "0px solid red";
            });
        },200); 
        refreshListView(listName, --times);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The JavaScript `Image` object has an `onload` callback that you can use. Example:

```
var myImage = new Image();
// Set the 'onload' callback to one of your functions
myImage.onload = imageLoadedCallback();
// Image starts loading once you set the 'src' attribute
myImage.src = "http://www.pippo.com/images/03.jpg";
```

This is a generic example of how to fire a callback once your images have been loaded.

#### Update:

Since you are getting an entire HTML list with images, I would use jQuery to find each `<img>`'s `src` attribute. Then, you can setup a callback like the one above for each `<img>` tag that jQuery finds in your HTML. Once the image loads, you can then attach it to your document.

Here's an example in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RustyTheBoyRobot/nfbkV/4/)

Comment: ok but, the code do not build the tags to append inside the ul tag. Instead it loads an entire piece of html via an ajax call and append it inside the ul, so no reference to the image (actually in the future the html code loaded might be different with no images or more images)

Comment: @chairam - My code that I posted was just to introduce you to the concept. You know your code, so I was thinking you could use this to create a solution for your needs. I've updated my answer to give you an idea of how to use this method in your code, but once again, it probably won't fit perfectly with your existing code. You need to understand the concepts and create your solution based on these concepts.

Comment: Thank you! I like the your idea of attach the refresh(sort of) to the onload callback, I will try it.

Comment: Just realize that loading each `<li>` like that will end up putting your images on your page in whatever order they are loaded in. If you want to enforce the list's order, you'll have to add some more code.